# Agreement in “comme vous l'avez indiqué(e)”

Tags: pronoms, accord, genre, participe-passé

Hi there I was trying to figure out if **"indiqué"** here needs to agree with **"réservation"** or not.

> Par contre la réservation est pour la nuit du 21 août et non du 21 juillet comme vous l'avez indiqué(e).

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2):

No agreement, because *réservation* is not the direct object of *vous avez indiqué*. The *l'* there is what's known as a [neuter object pronoun](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/neuter-object-pronoun/) - it doesn't replace *réservation*, but rather the idea of the date you indicated.

Comment: To clarify a little bit, this *le* in “comme vous l'avez indiqué” stands for the whole previous clause, that is, “la réservation est pour la nuit du 21 août et non du 21 juillet”.

Comment: Not quite, because "vous" indicated only 21 juillet.

Comment: Ah you're right. In fact it could either stand for “la réservation est pour la nuit du 21 juillet”, if the other person was mistaken, or for the whole thing, if the other person pointed out the mistake.